# Does anyone have any tips for developing a character in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is my first time in the series and I feel like I am all over the place. I'm a master at smithing, but everything else is in the 50's/60's. Only a few others are over 70.

This link made me rethink my choices: http://www.bigbadbob113.com/2011/11/29/elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-character-build-guide-rogue-2/
If you scroll down, this guy is a level lower than me and it looks like most of his stats are 60 or higher.

Don't get me wrong, I've had a lot of fun so far and I understand its what I make of it, but I just wonder if I could have planned things better or is this how things normally go?

To give you an idea of what I have - Level 41 Breton where I hack at people with an axe and use destruction spells with my other hand. I've liked it so far, but I'm starting to feel like I need to start over. I feel like I am just getting by on dying multiple times to try different tactics and occasionally get a crazy stroke of good luck.

I might also be burnt out because I spent close to 8 hours concentrating on smithing alone so I could go from level 85-100 and my enchanting is only 56. I am beginning to feel like I am working more than playing the game.

Any tips? Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: This is awfully open-ended in its current form. You seem to be more or less asking "how should I play the game?"

Comment: No, I think you're just misunderstanding the question. If you referred to the link I put in, you'd get a better understanding of what I mean. You didn't go to it did you? Apparently Alex understood where I was going with this and theorise had an idea too. Its about making the most out of my 24+hour experience. Seriously, do you have that much time to throw around all will nilly? I'm just annoyed you guys closed this question.

Comment: The two questions you ask are "Could I have planned things better?" and "Any tips?" If you reworded it to something specific like "How do I plan a a character build to maximize stat X, Y and Z", I would be much more inclined to vote to reopen. I am only trying to enforce the existing rules of the site.

Comment: As per the link, the writer talks about how he has the ultimate assasin/rogue b/c of the stats/perks he chose. I agree and apologize that my question was not as cut and dry as required. Overall, I really appreciate you reaching out to get a better grasp of what I was trying to say. My disappointment is a lot higher with those that asked nothing. I can't be annoyed with you for trying to keep a flow to how things work, but the whole point of these sites are for people to help. Which, you attempted. Thanks again.

Comment: And if you had asked "What stats/perks should I get for a strong assassin/rogue (or other type of character)", I would consider that a much better question, since it's asking for something specific and fairly objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better or for worse, I think that's kind of just how things go. Each player puts effort in to what they enjoy the most or what is most useful for the type of character they want to play. The latter of which is pretty straight forward, I think. If you love battle, focus on weapons and armor; if you want to be a mage, focus on enchanting, et cetera.

However, unlike Oblivion, you don't have to pick a skill every time you level up. Instead, leveling up your skills boosts your character level. Personally, I think this gives the player a lot more leeway in their character build, even if it does feel a little "all over the place" at times. This way, when you've maxed out all the "fighting" skills of your character, you *could* go back and just make them a kick ass mage as well.

Just my two cents, hope that answered part of your question at least.

Here's a decent reference for the leveling system in Skyrim: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have been looking for tips and tricks, just to make sure I get the most out of the game. Spending that much time with working on a character causes me to wonder if I am making the right choices. I really do appreciate the fact that I can wait to use a perk, but sometime they burn a whole in my pocket(so to speak) and I feel compelled to use it on something. Even if, in my mind, I've set it aside for something else. Besides, something else will open up and be available and I'm like wow! That will make a difference with this so...well, you get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

I used the IGN planner to plan my skills:

http://uk.ign.com/builds/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim//create

Comment: While that is really cool, (maybe its just my browser) I don't like it only because it doesn't show the skill level to achieve certain parts of the tier. It would be nice if I could put in a level and pick all the ones I want and it would show the characters abilities. (I claim this app idea! j/k)

Comment: It should do. Select the first branch of the alteration tree and it says you need level 15 alteration.